# How to configure a Windows Server 2008 VM to run with a specific resolution

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-server-2008, resolution

I have a build server running Windows Server 2008 R2. It runs a suite of automated acceptance tests which use the Selenium web driver. These tests are triggered automatically after a check-in and are failing due to having too small of a screen resolution. They are unable to access elements that are in a modal window because the modal window is too big to fit within the limited viewport that the tests are running in.

If I RDP into the machine at 1280 x 1024, I can run the tests and see that they pass just fine.  Is there a way to specify the "default" resolution for a windows box when a user isn't actually logged in with a monitor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a link, it looks like you can set your desired resolution with regedit:  http://philipflint.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/changing-the-screen-resolution-in-windows-server-2008-server-core/

From the URL:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{ClassID}000\DefaultSettings.XResolution
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{ClassID}000\DefaultSettings.Yresolution
```

The ClassID is a GUID. There is one for each display driver installed on your system. You can tell which one is currently in use as below the 0000 Key you will have another Key called “Volatile Settings”.